# js string interpolation fails in haml :javascript filter

Tags: javascript, haml

In a haml and jquery environment, the following haml fails:

```
#result

:javascript
  var foo = "result"
  $(`#${foo}`).text('some text')
```

Other tests show that string interpolation in a javascript filter like this:

```
#result

:javascript
  var foo = "qux"
  $('#result').text(`#${foo}`)
```

fails when '$' is immediately preceded by '#'. But it succeeds when there is a whitespace between!

How can I implement string interpolation within the javascript filter when I need '#' to precede the embedded value?

thanks in advance for any insight you can offer.

[Edit] of course @Barmar's concatenation suggestion is a good workaround. I also just found that this is reported as issue# 975 in the haml git repo

Comment: Try escaping the `#` with backslash. It's used for some special features in HAML, although I can't find any mention of `#$`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, just go back to string concatenation. `$('#' + foo)`

Comment: thanks @Barmar, escaping the `# ` doesn't work. I didn't even think of string concatenation, but of course it works just fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just concatenating the string, as `#` is special in HAML. `$('#' + foo)`